# asus aspire linux: how to attach a digicam?

Tags: linux, usb, camera

How do I attach a digital camera (canon s3) to an asus aspire one running linux?  I plug in the USB, the camera turns on, but nothing seems to happen on the computer side.

**update:** this netbook is so minimally configured that anything besides loading a pre-compiled module becomes more trouble than it's worth.  I ended up using an external USB card reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a question of whether you'd like to attach your camera as a camera or as a USB drive to get to your photos. Ensure that your camera is set to the proper mode (depends on the camera, check your manual). Plug your camera and check with dmesg if your system detected and configured modules for you.

Possible scenarios:

- you'd like to use your camera as a camera and Linux doesn't recognize your camera. Based on dmesg output (compare dmesg before and after plugging the device), search if there is a kernel module for your camera and if there is, check what package on your distro provides it.
- you'd like to use your camera as a camera and Linux recognized your device properly - check if you have been granted with proper privileges (e.g. on Arch Linux, one cannot use a camera if the user doesn't belong to the proper group).
- you'd like to use your camera as a USB drive but Linux doesn't recognize your device - I have never came across this situation with a working device.
- you'd like to use your camera as a USB drive and Linux does recognize your device - check if your device appeared in /dev (new sdX entry). If that is the case, try to mount it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Install something like http://www.gphoto.org/ or any other digital camera software set so you can get the pictures off.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no application installed or configured to automatically launch on connection of the camera. Use [**gPhoto2**](http://www.gphoto.org/), [**Picasa3**](http://picasa.google.com/linux/) or some similar photo management application to import the photos.

Answer (score 0):

First look at ./dev dir then if you find
A new record there try a cheese for gnome it support many many devices.
Last way you can mount your sdbx as disk